# iterate over key-value pairs in the object in sorted order

Tags: coffeescript, underscore.js

I'd like to iterate over an object

```
obj = c: 5, a: 10, b: 15
```

in the order based on key, e.g.

```
_.each obj, (value, key) -> console.log(key, value)
```

to get in the output this

```
# a 10
# b 15
# c 5
```

What is the shortest way to do this in CoffeeScript + underscore library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for k in _.keys(obj).sort()
  console.log k, obj[k]
  # you may also bind the value to a local var for convenience:
  # v = obj[k]
```

or one-line form: `console.log k, obj[k] for k in _.keys(obj).sort()`